# Como carregar um plugin de acordo com a largura da tela?

Tags: javascript

Olá, meu problema é o seguinte, tenho dois Plugins com funções semelhantes, porém eles não podem ser carregados ao mesmo tempo pois ocorrem erros.

Existe alguma maneira de carregar um determinado script de acordo com a resolução do navegador?

Ex:

```
<script>
    var largura = window.innerWidth;

    if(largura > X){
        //carregar plugin 1
        //<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/plugin1.js"></script>
    }

    else{
        //carregar plugin 1
        //<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/plugin2.js"></script>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A maneira que você colocou na pergunta deveria funcionar. Coloque mais informações acerca do seu código para ser mais claro. Aí poderemos compreender melhor.

Comment: seria algo assim, talvez seja mais facil do que eu imagino, porém eu não sei a syntaxe correta.

    var largura = window.innerWidth;

    if(largura > X){
  // seria este plugin
        // <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    }

    else{
        //carregar plugin 2
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vinicius, aqui vai uma resposta que pode funcionar:

```
 <script>
  function verifySize(){
    var largura = window.innerWidth;
    // Cria  a tag script
    script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");

    if(largura > 900){
      //carregar plugin 1 mudando o src pro script desejado
      script.src = "_js/jquery.fullPage.js";
    }else{
      //carregar plugin 2 mudando o src pro script desejado
      script.src = "_js/jquery.fullPage.js";
    }
    //Carrega o script dentro do body
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  // Caso você queira que o pluggin seja carregado somente ao entrar na pagina use o onload
  window.onload = verifySize;
  // Caso você queira que o pluggin seja carregado ao longo de mudanças dinâmicas no tamanho da janela use o onresize.
  window.onresize = verifySize;
</script>
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou certinho. Mto obrigado!